# View Threshold still exceeded with item limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, list-view-threshold

I have a list with multiple view. This list contains more the 5000 items. I know and understand that it means that any given view should not have more than 5000 items shown at any given time in it. But it seems that the ability to limit items in a view is pretty pointless to help in that matter.

I know that, even with the filter, there are more than 5000 items that are return in my list. That means that the filter is not enough. So I specified a hard item limit on the number of items returned by the view (100 items flat I don't need more to be returned by the view at any given time). But the Threshold is still exceeded, even if the request is very light. I only want the top 100 items of my view.

Is there a way to have such behavior on SharePoint Online ? When the filter is not sufficient to limit the number of items. I don't really understand why the item limit is not able to prevent list threshold issues.

I cannot make a more precise filter since it would need to be applied on a date that vary by the minutes. You cannot make a filter with minutes precision, only day precision ([Today]-xdays).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommend the following for managing large lists and libraries:

**Index columns**

Index the column that you wish to use to filter the view.

**Use the modern experience**

The modern list view lazy loads data as you scroll down. This may not be helpful for filtered views but provides a better experience in large lists.

More information:

[Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

[Living Large with Large Lists and Large Libraries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/large-lists-large-libraries-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Many articles, including Microsoft’s, mention indexing columns in the context of resolving list view threshold issues, but they do not specify *why* it helps.  I understand an index makes a database query more performant, but it won’t change the number of matches that are returned (which, if over 5,000, is a problem).  If anyone knows *why* indexing helps resolve list view threshold issues, I would love to know.

Comment: You can run queries using the indexed columns, e.g. show me all the items in the list where IndexedColumn A equals A. You can then use paging to return those results in reasonable amounts (less than 5k time).