# Item limit of 5000, is it the same for pages?

Tags: pages, boundaries

About the 5000 limit, is exactly the same for the page library? Considering you can only have one per site, how do you accomplish large knowledge base sites with 10000 pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pages are the same as items and docs

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/modern-portal-limits?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 1):

5000 is not the item limit, it's the list view threshold limit inside SharePoint that can render items at one go, especially if you're in SharePoint classic view. The exact item limit is 3 million, so 10000 is still a long way to go.

Read on: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0 and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits.

If you're displaying your knowledge base with Page Library View, consider using pagination by going to Settings > Views (select your default View) > then edit the Item Limit to display in batches.
[image]

The other way is to go to the SharePoint Central Admin (if it's not SharePoint Online). Go to Application Management > Manage Web Applications. Then select the web application and click General Settings > Resource Throttling.

[image]

You can change this setting, but my advice is to avoid modifying this and go with the first approach. Changing this to a bigger number will have an impact on your SharePoint SQL Database Server. You can also change little by little and monitor your database workload.

**Note**: In SharePoint 2016 or 2019 or Online version using modern site template, this setting is useless as the data is rendered partially as you scroll. Only when you decided to go to the classic view, then it matters.
In SharePoint Online, you can't change the Resource Throttling and it will stay at 5000.

Comment: it is online and the limit affects the items even when the paging is up to 20

Comment: What is your SharePoint site template currently? Is it modern or classic?

Comment: modern modern modern

Comment: If your site is modern, and your Pages Library view is also within modern view, then there's nothing to be worried about. 5000 list view threshold will not kick in. The rest of the page will be loaded when you scroll. Try look at this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/large-lists-large-libraries-in-sharepoint.

Comment: I guess you have never seen what happens when you pass 5000 in real life so you rely on "what's written on the web". Sorry that's not what I want

Comment: I'm sorry if you don't get the answer right, while I'm also trying to understand your question. I'm writing based on my real experience encountering a document library with even more than 500K+ items and comparing it against the documentation too. It's just too simple, with classic view (though your site template is modern), you will be limited with 5000 items at one go. But it won't happen with modern view, where you can keep scrolling down.
Maybe it will help if you can elaborate more on your question by giving some explanatory screenshot/images?

Comment: Please take a look at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289320/view-threshold-still-exceeded-with-item-limit. It's the same issue as yours. When you switch to modern view, the list will be lazy-loaded and the 5000 limit will not kick in.

Comment: when you pass 5000 it might happen that a document library does not accept anymore documents or prevents you from deleting existing ones, or prevents you from adding a column or sorting and filtering comes out wrong, these have nothing to do with paging since the standard paging is 20. With doc libraries you can at least minimise the problem with folders or worst case create multiple libraries, with PAGE libraries it is bizarre to use folders and it is not possible/healthy to create multiple page libraries, hence my question.